# Error running PS Script to reindex user profiles in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, user-profile-service

I have reused the managed property RefinableString00 and mapped it to the crawled property People:Office.  I need to reindex user profiles for an organization with 600 employees. Given that this is SharePoint online, there is not the option for a full crawl of user profiles.  The options I have right now are 1) have every employee re-enter the metadata in the office field and hope that they listen so that the items will be picked up on a continuous crawl, or 2) run the following script that will reindex user profiles.  The script is from Mikael Svenson.  The two issues I am having is the error "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'username'."  I am using my login who is the global admin.  A second issue is that I needed to change the property to Office which is a string as opposed to a date time which is what was originally in the script. I am unsure if the -Value is correct on line 36 where I use the Set-PnPUserProfileProperty to set the -Property Office.  Can anyone assist me?

```
 # Force save by setting a random varOffice value
        Set-PnPUserProfileProperty -Account $p.AccountName -PropertyName "Office" -Value [String]::"reindex placeholder"
        if ( $varOffice -eq "" ) {
            Write-Host "`tKeeping varOffice as not defined" -ForegroundColor Green
            Set-PnPUserProfileProperty -Account $p.AccountName -PropertyName "Office" -Value [String]::Empty
        }
        else {
            $oldOffice = [String]::Parse($varOffice)
            Write-Host "`tRe-setting varOffice to" $oldOffice -ForegroundColor Green
            Set-PnPUserProfileProperty -Account $p.AccountName -PropertyName "Office" -Value $oldOffice
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use command below to verify administrator credential:

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com –Credentials (Get-Credential)
```

And change the property value without [String]::

```
# Force save by setting a random varOffice value
        Set-PnPUserProfileProperty -Account $p.AccountName -PropertyName "Office" -Value "reindex placeholder"
        if ( $varOffice -eq "" ) {
            Write-Host "`tKeeping varOffice as not defined" -ForegroundColor Green
            Set-PnPUserProfileProperty -Account $p.AccountName -PropertyName "Office" -Value ""
        }
        else {
            $oldOffice = [String]::Parse($varOffice)
            Write-Host "`tRe-setting varOffice to" $oldOffice -ForegroundColor Green
            Set-PnPUserProfileProperty -Account $p.AccountName -PropertyName "Office" -Value $oldOffice
        }
    }
```